# Automatically schedule future deployment in Octopus

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy

**Update: I found executing script on the octopus server is now available in [version 3.3](https://octopus.com/blog/octopus-deploy-3.3), I haven't update my octopus yet but I will take that would work as designed. I'm still wondering if there is a better way to do this without octo.exe?**

The task I'm trying to accomplish is after each successful production deployment, automatically schedule a DR deployment to happen next 24 hours.

My desired approach is have octopus do it.

I added a new Octopus step at the end of the deployment only runs upon success of previous step. I attempted to use `octo deploy-release --deployAt` can be found [here](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Scheduled+Deployments) in the newly created step.

My challenge is, a script step requires me to pick a target role, which means it will be executed on a tentacle. Also, presence of Octo.exe is required.

I tried to create my own octopus step template, a deployment target role is still required in my customized step.

```
{
  "Id": "ActionTemplates-2",
  "Name": "Octopus - Schedule Deployment",
  "Description": "Schedule a future octopus deployment",
  "ActionType": "Octopus.Script",
  "Version": 3,
  "Properties": {
    "Octopus.Action.Script.Syntax": "PowerShell",
    "Octopus.Action.Script.ScriptBody": "--hide--"
  },
  "SensitiveProperties": {},
  "Parameters": [
    {
      "Name": "OctoPath",
      "Label": "Path for Octo.exe",
      "HelpText": "Location for octo.exe",
      "DefaultValue": null,
      "DisplaySettings": {
        "Octopus.ControlType": "SingleLineText"
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "projName",
      "Label": "Project Name",
      "HelpText": "The name of the project should be deployed",
      "DefaultValue": null,
      "DisplaySettings": {
        "Octopus.ControlType": "SingleLineText"
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "days",
      "Label": "Days",
      "HelpText": "The days in future this deployment would happen",
      "DefaultValue": null,
      "DisplaySettings": {
        "Octopus.ControlType": "SingleLineText"
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "hours",
      "Label": "Hours",
      "HelpText": "The hours in future this deployment would happen",
      "DefaultValue": null,
      "DisplaySettings": {
        "Octopus.ControlType": "SingleLineText"
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "env",
      "Label": "Environment to deploy",
      "HelpText": "The environment next deployment should happen",
      "DefaultValue": null,
      "DisplaySettings": {
        "Octopus.ControlType": "SingleLineText"
      }
    }
  ],
  "$Meta": {
    "ExportedAt": "2016-04-20T13:58:54.263Z",
    "OctopusVersion": "3.2.0",
    "Type": "ActionTemplate"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to alter the template to get rid of the role selection and have octopus server directly execute it as it does for Azure script step?

Is there any another way we can have octopus server automatically schedule the deployment without external help? I guess this go back to first problem, I may still need octopus to run something on the server side.

Note: We kick off production deployment manually, thus I don't have another tool waiting for the response of the deployment. I think it is possible to have a process regularly call out the last deployment and do some analysis then schedule new deployment accordingly but this is not as clean as have octopus do it directly. Injecting octo.exe to a random production machine is not desired at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create new WebAPI project in C#, pull in the Octopus.Deploy nuget package,

write code that accepts HTTP requests, and deals with the scheduling logic.

Host that project on the same server as Octopus server itself. Should be 20-30 minute job to set the website up in IIS.

In your deployment process, add step that creates http request, and done. You could go even one step further, and have the site/service listen for every successful deployment, and do decisions based on that, such that other projects don't have to add extra steps to octopus deployment process.

As you said, polling is also viable option.

Alternatively, if you're on Octopus deploy 3.0, they already expose REST API, I am not sure if it's powerful enough to allow you create scheduled deployment, but you could explore that: https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusDeploy-Api/wiki/Releases

I agree floating octo.exe in production servers is bad idea. It might get out of sync, and your production server shouldn't deal with this.

Comment: REST API doesn't seem to be offering scheduling for release. In this use case, I will probably upgrade octopus to 3.3 and utilize the new build-in step to make it cleaner, but creating customized API is a truly inspirational idea to me. I can easily think of many other cases this can be used, especially on some ancient monitoring system. Thank you for the help.